# Azure Pipelines Schedule to Run on specific day is not working

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines, schedule

I am trying to configure azure pipeline schedules for running it on a specific day but it is not taking day from 27 to 31.

Please refer below screenshot for better understanding the issue.

[image]

trigger:

- main

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

schedules:

- cron: "0 18 26-31 * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
  include:

  - main
    always: true

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Executing the pipeline during the last 6 days of the month:**

Since not every month would have 31 days, you want to execute the pipeline on the last 6 days independently from the number of days in the month.

Azure pipelines use [NCrontab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) which does not provide support for specifying days relative to the end of the month as confirmed by the author in [this issue](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/issues/9#issuecomment-205448445).

One possible solution (following the suggestion in [the following comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/361#issuecomment-357321660)) is to use a range of days that include the last six days in the worst case (February ending on the 28th) which you would express as `23-31`.

Then, you must have a task in your pipeline that checks that the current date is within the range of the last 6 days of the current month, and stop the pipeline if it is not.

As a result, your pipeline will be executed for the last 6 days of the month in the best case and for the last 9 days in the worst case but this will be handled by the additional task explained in the previous sentence.

**Running the pipeline using schedule triggers:**

If you want to run your pipeline by using schedule triggers, you need to disable PR and CI triggers.

```
pr: none
trigger: none
```

Comment: Thank you Nadine Raiss for the reply.
Yes I had set pr and trigger none. I had tried with cron: "0 18 27-31 * *" but it is only showing Scheduled runs on 27 october only.

Could you please provide cron expression for 31 october only.
and what cron expression we will use for last 6 days for every month.

Comment: I have updated my answer following your comment.

Comment: Hi Nadine, I had tried with 23-31 but in scheduled run it showing trigger from 23 to 27, however I am not able to understand why it is not showing 28, 29 ,30 and 31 as it is straight forward thing.

did we missing something regarding cron tab expression specific for Azure Devops.

Comment: Did you use this exact expression `0 18 23-31 * *`? You can see on [the following link](https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/?expression=0+18+23-31+*+*) that this expression results in the correct dates. Normally, in the preview of Scheduled runs on Azure DevOps pipeline, it only shows the next few runs scheduled for the current week.

Comment: Thank you Nadine Raiss. It's working with 0 18 23-31 * * now, however when i was tried  earlier 31 oct is not coming.

Comment: Yes I think that time it only showing for current week. Thanks a lot Nadine for your help :)